# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have a string 2016. I am wondering how can I parse this string to a date time? 
I have tried `Datetime.ParseExact` but it said it is not a valid format

```
string period = "2016"
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(period, "YYYY", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `"yyyy"` instead for `YYYY` then you will get the expected answer;

```
string period = "2016";
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(period, "yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

You can check More DateTime Formats [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: you should marked it as answer to close the question. :)

Comment: @down-Voter : appreciate the spirit and thanks for the support. This is an open community not the Place to show Personal revenge.